# Characterizing $C_p(X)$ for regular or Tychonoff space $X$.

Tags: general-topology

Are there any known characterizations for $C_p(X)$ Given that $X$ is regular or even Tychonoff?

$C_p(X)$ is the space of continuous real valued functions $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb R$
with the topology of pointwise convergence.

Thank you!

Comment: What does the $p$ stand for?

Comment: point. The point open topology

Comment: So you endow the space of continuous functions $C(X)$ with the subspace topology it inherits from the product topology $C(X)\subset\prod_{X}\Bbb R$ ?

Comment: I have more frequently seen this called as *topology of pointwise convergence*. It is simply the topology inherited from the topological product $\mathbb R^X$.

Comment: What kind of characterization are you looking for? As a topological vector space? As a topological algebra?

Comment: I am reading example 94 from "Counterexamples in Topology". The space described in there is completely regular. In addition, every continuous function over $X$ is constant for all but counteble set of points. Can I, for example say that given $A \subset C_p(X)$ and a basis set $B \subset C_p(X)$, then $A \cap B$ has a non empty interior?

Comment: Or for example, is this space Hausdorff?

Comment: from what said here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology, can I say that $C_p(X)=\mathbb R^X$ is regular when $X$ is regular?

Comment: The product is $T_0$ ($T_1, T_2,$ (completely) regular) if and only if all of the factors are $T_0$ ($T_1, T_2,$ (completely) regular). Then $C_p(X)$ is $T_0$ ($T_1, T_2,$ (completely) regular) since it is a subspace of the product.

Comment: If you are interested in properties of $C_p(X)$, then [A Cp-Theory Problem Book](http://books.google.sk/books?id=EcINw8FHIAoC) by V.V.Tkachuk might be useful you.

Comment: It seems that the questions you asked in your comment are different from what you asked in your post. I would understand *characterize* $C_p(X)$ as: *Find conditions on $Y$ which are fulfilled if and only if there is an $X$ such that* $Y\cong C_p(X)$.

Comment: ok. I will think about all that you have said. Thank you all for your answers!!